# CSS li items stacking on top each other

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm building a mobile menu and my list items are trying to unexpectedly stack on top of each other. I imagine that I can somehow set the same distance to the top or something like that since they stack on top of each other but can't seem to find and fix the issue.

**CSS:**

```
nav#nav-mobile {
    position: relative;            
    display: none; }
nav#nav-mobile ul#vertnav li{
    display: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 99;
    opacity: 0.8;
    background-color: #000; }
nav#nav-mobile ul#vertnav li ul {
    display: none;
 }
nav#nav-mobile li{
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin: 0 5px;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #000; }
nav#nav-mobile li:last-child {
    border-bottom: none; }
nav#nav-mobile a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 30px; }
nav#nav-mobile a:hover {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff; }
#nav-trigger {
    display: block; }
.topnav {
    display: none; }
nav#nav-mobile { 
    display: block; }  
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<nav id="nav-mobile">

<ul id="vertnav">
 <li class="favoritter open expanded" style="display: list-item;">
    <span class="vertnav-cat"><a href="#"><span>Favoritter</span></a></span>
  <ul>
    <li class="mest-solgte expanded" style="display: list-item;">
      <span class="vertnav-cat"><a href="#"><span>mest solgte</span></a></span>

    </li>
    <li class="vi-anbefaler expanded" style="display: list-item;">
      <span class="vertnav-cat"><a href="#"><span>Vi anbefaler</span></a></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li class="favoritter open expanded" style="display: list-item;">
        <span class="vertnav-cat"><a href="#"><span>Favoritter item2</span></a></span>
      <ul>
        <li class="item1 expanded" style="display: list-item;">
          <span class="vertnav-cat"><a href="#"><span>item1</span></a></span>        
        </li>
        <li class="item2 expanded" style="display: list-item;">
          <span class="vertnav-cat"><a href="#"><span>item2</span></a></span>
        </li>
      </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Look at the LI items "Favoritter" and "Favoritter item2" - these are the two that stack on top of each other.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. Could you be clearer?

Comment: @chiapa , I have tried to clarify and edited my answer a bit.

Comment: i tried to edit your question but gave up. You should at least try hard enough to format your code before posting it mate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the parent `li` are positioned absolutely.

Remove that.

```
nav#nav-mobile ul#vertnav li {
    display: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    /*
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    */
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 99;
    opacity: 0.8;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vm4wegzo/1/)

Comment: this works, so they all show, but in your JSFiddle demo you get each item to have 100% with, on my menu I get three columns instead. So they don't have full width of the menu.